# Remove border around vegaEmbed geoshape generated by altair?

Tags: python, vega, vega-lite, altair

In the below image, observe the border around a map generated from `Chart.save()` to either HTML or JSON canvas (the border is inside the canvas, not CSS styled).

[image]

For any other type of mark, one would expect to be able to use `Chart.configure_view()` to set `strokeWidth=0` to remove the border, but this does not appear to affect this geoshape chart.

The vegaEmbed [embed options](https://github.com/vega/vega-embed#options) do not appear to document what creates this border.

Is it possible to style or remove the border?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to remove the border is using `configure_view(strokeWidth=0)`.

Here is an example, using the most recent version of Altair and the most recent version of Vega-Lite:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

counties = alt.topo_feature(data.us_10m.url, 'counties')
source = data.unemployment.url

alt.Chart(counties).mark_geoshape().encode(
    color='rate:Q'
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='id',
    from_=alt.LookupData(source, 'id', ['rate'])
).project(
    type='albersUsa'
).configure_view(
    strokeWidth=0
)
```

[image]

If you see different results, it might be that your frontend renderer is out of date, and you should make certain you're using the most recent version of Vega-Lite to render your chart.

Comment: Thank you, you were correct; updating everything and using `configure_view(strokeWidth=0)` indeed removed the border. I'm not sure about the correct procedure, but I'll leave my question up for others who might bump into their own user errors (though perhaps the question should be edited?)