# Altair remove border in LayerChart

Tags: python, altair

I am trying to remove the border from an altair chart.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56642771/3284713) works perfectly but it fails when I try to visualize a layered chart.

In my setting I have two charts, one for the contour `m1` and one with the coordinates assigned to each category and properly colored `m2`.

I can add the setting `configure_view(strokeWidth=0)` to each and I can plot them independently, however when trying to plot `m1+m2` I get an error.

> Objects with "config" attribute cannot be used within LayerChart. Consider defining the config attribute in the LayerChart object instead.

I then defined `m1` and `m2`without the `config_view` attribute but now I can't figure out how to define it for the final object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is as simple as creating a new object and setting the attribute on that object.

```
layeredmap=m1+m2
layeredmap.configure_view(StrokeWidth=0)
```

Alternatively, it is enough to use parenthesis and define the attribute while plotting:

```
(m1+m2).configure_view(StrokeWidth=0)
```

Comment: strokedWidth should be changed to strokeWidth?

Comment: @chyx I honestly can't recall anymore but it likely is a typo.
The documentation seems to agree with your comment as well. Will updated