# Altair change border color LayerChart

Tags: python, altair

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59028248/3284713).

I was able to "hide" the border by setting `.configure_view(strokedWidth=0)`.
Unfortunately, converting the `.svg` file to `.emf` makes the border appear again as a very thin line (possible reasons [in comments 4 and 6 here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1658698).

Is there a way to set the border color (as the background color, so that it will technically be invisible) or eventually to extend the border so that it doesn't touch the map edge and I will simply be able to crop it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [jakevdp's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59071474/3284713)
I had a look at the `configure_view` [documentation](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/toplevel/altair.Chart.html?highlight=configure_view#altair.Chart.configure_view).

I solved this by setting the stroke color to white (same as the background color).

```
map.configure_view(stroke='white')
```

Answer (score 2):

You might try using `strokeOpacity=0`, to make the stroke transparent. The docstring of `configure_view` will show you other available arguments that you could try as well.

Comment: Hi, I tried with `StrokeOpacity=0` (and also a combination of it and `strokedWidth` but unfortunately the border keeps popping back again when converting to `.emf`.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your conversion software rather than an issue with Vega-Lite.

Comment: I am aware of that. However your suggestion helped. It is possible to set the color of the border. Setting it equal to the background color made the border invisible and solved my issue =)